# How can files with the exact same name be created in a folder?

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, centos-7, ntfs-3g

This is not something that I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to figure out an issue that has already happened.

One of our LIDAR systems in the field returned a data collection drive with duplicate files.  Every single file on the drive had a second duplicate with the exact same name, time, date, and size.  To the best of my knowledge this should be impossible.

The files are written on a Linux PC (CentOS 7) but they are stored on NTFS.  This is because they are processed on Windows PCs.  We've run this software and used the same types of drives for years.

I tried to think about ways this could occur but I couldn't come up with any.  If somehow two instances of the storage software were running they would be fighting over the same file, not writing an identical one in the same directory.  This should be impossible.

I then thought that maybe it was a fluke with Windows File Explorer displaying the files.  I had them take the drive out and put it into another PC and it still showed the same.  I then wondered if there were hidden characters.  However, when they transferred the data to their server it recognized that the filenames were identical and prompted them to skip or overwrite each duplicate.

I would write this off as a fluke but the customer is adamant about trying to get to the bottom of this.  Can anyone give me any insight or even a theory as to how this happened?

Comment: Is capitalization the same between both files? If you do an MD5 comparison, do both files have the same hash?

Comment: What does the `file` program show about the two files?

Comment: Yes, capitalization was exactly the same.  I didn't think about doing an MD5 comparison.  Unfortunately the customer has already reformatted the drives so I can't do one now.  If it happens again though that'll be my first step.

Comment: The customer has already reformatted the drives in the field.  Unfortunately I never had physical access to them.  I only had screenshots and log files.  The logs didn't show anything out of the ordinary though.  If it happens again I'll try the MD5 and also look at them with the `file` program.  Until then all I can do is provide the customer with my best theory as to what happened.  At this point I don't have much of one though.

Comment: Was it on Windows or Linux that the file names appeared identical? Remember that Windows has a tendency to suppress file extensions. If the customer was serious about getting to the bottom of the problem, he should have kept the evidence.

Comment: It was on Windows that the file names appeared identical.  The file extensions were shown in the screenshots.

Comment: I also let the customer know that if this ever happened again to send the files directly to me.

Comment: There could be a hidden extension on one of the files, eg `file.log` and `file.log.lnk` will appear identical in Explorer, though you will see the difference in `cmd`.

Comment: I would definitively run a `dir /A` on the PC to check for hidden extensions or such. Next time, don't keep the files but the filesystem, by creating an image (even `dd` would do).

Comment: This may be the result of filesystem metadata corruption. File Names and folder locations are just metadata that the FS tracks, so perhaps a check with Chkdsk or fsck is in order.

Comment: given that these were not simply sidecar files, I am guessing one copy of each may have been a symbolic link or similar. Note also that NTFS is a closed format that is not fully publicly documented and Linux support was reverse engineered. It may be possible there is a piece of software with close-to-metal access that managed to sidestep restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen: one file had a regular "a" (ASCII 0x61), the other had a very similar looking "Cyrillic small letter a" (U+0430). There are many characters in the Cyrillic аlphаbet that look exactly like lаtin ones ("e", "o" are two other frequent ones)(*).

One way to identify the problem (and the baddie): `dir` or `ls` to file and look at the output with a hex editor (in Linux you can also use the shorter: `ls * | hd`).

IIRC it is also possible to use Unicode "ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)" character in a file name.

(*) I have hidden some in the text of this answer...